# how to do bhakti with non bhakt parents?

Tags: sin, bhakti, parents

I am a jee aspirant belongs to a middle class family and my parents wants to see me studying any time every second. they behave very angry and awkward when they caught me listning a bhajan on youtube. and doing bhakti is very awkward in front of my parents. I can't leave my home because I think it's a huge sin and also it's very hard to survive without money and job. sometimes I become very angry and uncomfortable and I shout on my family members. What should I do? Can I ever be able to worship my god?

Answer (score 1):

Bhakti comes from within and is not an external process. You can do it without
anyone knowing or seeing. I feel that you have a confused state of mind. Clear your thoughts and set your priorities. I know it is very difficult to live without money, but your have to keep your mind peaceful. Seek help from friends and relatives. May be they can guide you.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve success in any field, **discipline** and timing are key players. As you are preparing for higher studies, bhakti will help you to keep away from distractions in this age. It can also become a distraction if you are watching youtube bhajans or 3-4 hour long katha, everyday.

If you are not considering to become a monk, then IMO you should fix some specific duration to listen bhajans or anything you consider as bhakti. You can easily bargain this time with your family.

Once the time is gone, its gone and it will apply whether you want to study or watch youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Great question?
Parents gave birth to you. Please do not exhibit bhakthi towards those who do not like.
Parents are moulded from olden days to exhibit bhakthi only in old age. Anyone very devoted in young age receive more criticism.
Bhakthi is needed for human. Please obey parents at home. Study well before them.
To exhibit bhakthi visit temples in person & meditate there for an hour. God is beyond critics, schools or even money. In TIER-1 countries like Western EUROPE, Smart-Metro Asian cities all are wealthy. No one is poor. But it will be shocking to know what they eat for survival. They do eat worms, crabs, snakes, tamed animals and rice/ wheat because they never believe GOD. They believe that only fittest survive and claim fittest as the one who can adapt to any environment. This is impossible. Such TIER-1 extremely hot(Emirati), extremely cold(Europe), extremely oceanic stressed Asian countries(HKG, Malay, Srilanka, Indonesia) etc funded education exams in India. TIER-2 like India countries must follow TIER-1 for development due to BANK LOANS and funds. But, BHAKTHI cant be understood by education by expectation & hopes.
Answer: Get educated for earning money but try worshipping God truly.